# connecting to sql server compact

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I just created a sql server compact 3.5 database with the visual studio 2010 assistant (localdatabase). When i click the run button (start debugging), I can see that my database disconnect in server explorer (red X). I click refresh and it looks like connected, but again, if I click start, the database connection stops (again red X).

Do I have to configure something else in my develop computer or does VS2010 automatically does it?

Hope I did explain my self. Thank in advance!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, thanks for viewing my post. I don't get any error, I just can not save any data to my database. I can save data only when my app is running, but when I close my app I check the database and I don't have any records saved.

I check my database name in server explorer and it has the red X (disconnected)

Comment: Did you look in your bin/debug folder for a copy of the database file with data in it?

Comment: Ok. I already got it, I did checked my bin/debug database from VS and I saw the records now. Thank you ver much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look in your bin/debug folder for a copy of the database file with data in it?

Comment: Thank you ErikEJ, I tried to give a positive vote but I can't till I have at least 15 reputation